# How to “forget” previous categorization about a sender?

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

I am using Gmail Tabs (Primary, Social and Promotions).

I moved a newsletter of a website I like from Promotions to Primary and clicked "yes" when Gmail asked me if I wanted to keep that behavior for all future email of that sender.

Now I would like to "forget" this setting because I would like to see if emails of that website keep landing in the Promotions tab or they "improved" their behavior and they now land in the Primary tab (without my instructions).

Is it possible?